# E_FAIL (0x80004005) Virtualbox Error in Windows [Even with Hypervisor Disabled]

Tags: virtualbox

The virtual box gives the error E_FAIL (0x80004005);

Although the majority of solutions for this problem is that the windows hypervisor is being enabled this is not the case.

I could verify that the windows hypervisor was disabled by going to:
**Windows** -> **Applications and Resources** -> (on the left of the screen) **Programs and Resources** -> **Activate or Deactivate Windows Resources**

[image: Hyper-V disable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Oracle Virtualbox website and download the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack, because the extension pack may be missing this can cause the error, even if hyper-v is disable.

Answer (score 1):

I had also error E_FAIL (0x80004005), and I fixed it by installing an older version of VirtualBox (version 6.1.44). 
For me also windows hypervisor and other solutions that you can find over the internet haven't solved this issue.